# Roth IRA Conversion and taking money out

Tags: united-states, income-tax, roth-ira

A person who is over 59.5 years of age has an traditional IRA worth 1 million dollars and no Roth IRAs.
On Monday, he converts the traditional IRA to a Roth IRA. On Tuesday, due to an unexpected expense, he takes 1 million dollars out of his Roth IRA. I claim that there is no tax consequence for taking out the 1 million dollars because he is taking back is own money. That is, earnings are taken last. Do I have this right?

I live in the United States.

Comment: What happened to the _tax due_ when the Traditional IRA was converted to a Roth IRA?

Comment: @DilipSarwate It was paid when the conversion was done.

Answer (score 6):

There would be a 10% early withdrawal penalty on the amount withdrawn from the Roth IRA. You are correct that earnings are taken out last, and in this case there are no earnings, but no contributions either. There is only conversions, and taxable conversions withdrawn in the first 5 years are subject to the 10% early withdrawal penalty (but no tax).

This would not meet the requirements for a qualified distribution because although the owner is over 59.5 years old, they have not had a Roth IRA for 5 years. So it's a non-qualified distribution and the tax and penalty is determined by the ordering rules. If they wait 5 years after converting before withdrawing, then it would be completely tax- and penalty-free.

Also worth pointing out that converting 1 million dollars in one year is probably a terrible idea unless they are extremely wealthy. It's better to convert a smaller amount each year to keep the marginal tax rate down.

Comment: I thought that the penalty only applies to earnings taken out, not your own money. Do you agree that there is no income tax on the withdrawals?

Comment: @Bob Agree there is no income tax. But there is a 10% penalty in the first 5 years after a taxable conversion/rollover. See https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i5329#idm139853308294144.

Comment: However, if they've once contributed to Roth IRA more than 5 years ago (even if they do not have any money in Roth IRA now), I believe that they would not have a penalty.

Comment: @user102008 Correct, it would be a qualified distribution then. Since the question says they have "no Roth IRAs", I assumed that was not the case, but I suppose it's possible.

Comment: @CraigW Do you now believe your answer is wrong? If so, I am thinking you should correct it?

Comment: @Bob I think this answer is still correct. The question seems to be ”Is there a tax consequence for immediately withdrawing from a new Roth IRA converted from a traditional IRA when the person previously had no IRAs?"  This addresses that question exactly. Even if there's no income tax, the IRS handles the 10% penalty and even calls it an "additional 10% tax": https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc557

Comment: Correction to a more relevant link - can't edit my comment any more: https://www.irs.gov/publications/p590b#en_US_2020_publink1000231065

Comment: @TylerW Here is a quote from your link: Unless one of the exceptions listed below applies, you must pay the 10% additional tax on the taxable part of any distributions that aren't qualified distributions. You notice that the 10% only applies to the taxable part of the distribution. I think we agreed that the 1 million dollar distribution is not taxable. Therefore, it seems to me that there the 10% penalty does not apply.

Comment: @Bob Ugh yeah this is hard (surprise)! So the question is still about what's considered taxable, and the answer seems to be "earnings" according to this: https://www.kiplinger.com/article/taxes/t046-c001-s001-tax-rules-for-roth-withdrawals.html, but I don't know enough to write up an answer on anything further. Regardless, I'm going to stop cluttering this answer with my comments. It sounds like you have a proposed answer of your own, so I'd encourage you to write up a separate answer as you see it if you'd like more discussion.

Comment: @Bob 10% penalty on the taxable part of the _conversion_. The 1 million dollar conversion is definitely taxable, so if a non-qualified distribution withdraws part of that taxable conversion within 5 years, it will incur the penalty.

Comment: *taxable conversions withdrawn in the first 5 years are subject to ... penalty* is this the first 5 years the Roth IRA is open, or the first 5 years after the conversion? Doesn't each conversion have its own 5-year waiting period?

Comment: @yoozer8 First 5 years after the conversion. Each conversion has its own 5-year waiting period, and they're first-in, first-out. For example, a taxable conversion performed in 2016 through 2020 and withdrawn in 2020 would be subject to the 10% penalty according to the instructions at https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i5329#idm139853308294144.

Comment: @CraigW There is no tax penalty for converting a traditional IRA to a Roth IRA. However, there may (and very likely a large amount) of tax due. Do you disagree with that?

Comment: @Bob No, I don't disagree with that. I sort of made that point in the last paragraph, but the question didn't really ask about taxes on the conversion, just the withdrawal.